# Getting error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' when trying to install Jupyter Notebook using pip on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the command on the Jupyter website,

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

but I get the error:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1
pip3 install jupyter
           ^                                                     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried many different commands, and they all produce the same error. I'm reluctant to install Anaconda, as I already have python installed on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the same commands I found on their website:
This is what I found:
If Python 3 is installed:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

For Python 2:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install jupyter
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did use these commands at first (still returns an error), but then on their help page and official documentation it tells you to use the commands I stated,

Comment: Are you able to run Python at all from CMD. If not you may have to change your system’s PATH variable to the python install directory

Comment: yeah, I can run python. I figured out that I didn't have pip in my PATH environment variable. I fixed it now.

Comment: You saved me! It turns out that I'm installing the python3 version of jupyter with python2. Installing it with python3 makes it work!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution. I needed to add pip to my PATH Environment variable. I had python added, but I also needed to add the directory where pip was located.